# Kendo React chart display issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, charts, kendo-ui, frontend

In Kendo react I am using a stacked bar chart to display data. However if the difference between the numbers is very big, the bar looks disproportionate. How can i make it look more proportioned so that the smaller numbers have a wider space.

I tried what was shown in the documentation, and asked for help from chatgpt however no result.[Screenshot!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OOnjA.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.